# Tried and tested ways to automate load tests with Maven

Tags: java, performance, maven, load-testing

I'm trying to figure out the best way to automate the execution of and result recording of load tests. We currently use Maven; ideally the solution would be executed as part of the Maven project life-cycle, so that people do not need so spend time on effort setting up the tests.

It should save the output of the tests (e.g. as some files that could be committed into version control), and should have the sense to not compare tests run on a dusty x486 with a 8 core Sparc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter) is another Apache project which is very well adapted for automation (you can control most things from the command line); there are also several plugins that you can use to integrate it into Maven. Personally, I think this is by far the best tool for this sort of requirement.

You still need to create the actual tests to run and decide which environment to use - but this will always be the case no matter which tool you choose.

Have a look [here](http://jmeter.lazerycode.com/), [here](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2009/10/automated_performance_testing_using_jmeter_and_maven/) and [here](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin).